# Get File Path to Read in Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I want to say that I'm new to Azure functions and probably what I'm trying to do may not make sense.
Here we go.
In the function I am creating I have to import content into a database. Whenever I do this I validate if the content is new or if it is a simple update to the data.
After that I take an email template that is in the root "*root/EmailsTemplate/MyTemplate.html*" I fill in with the data that I collected and send.
However, I cannot access this repository directly. I've seen that I can use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`
or also the `ExecutionContext`, however they all send me to the *\bin\Debug\net472* execution folder. Do I have to use one of these and go back in the folders? Or is there another way? And how will it behave later in the Azure environment?

I use Azure Function V1 (.net Framework 4.7.2)

Thanks

Comment: So is MyTemplate.html a file that's part of your project ? If so in solution view -> properties for Copy to Output Directory select Copy Always / Copy if newer

Comment: thank you very much auburg, that was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As auburg says, set the below properties of the file can copy the file to `\bin\Debug\net472` after you build the project:

[image]

[image]

And if your function app is on azure, then the content of the root directory is the files in `\bin\Debug\net472`.